# How can i filter google images curl by width-height?

Tags: php, ajax, json, curl

I need help about google images curl. I can't filter results by width-height.

```
function get_url_contents($url) {
    $crl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1;     .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}

$json = get_url_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?  v=1.0&q=keyword');

$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->responseData->results as $result) {
    $results[] = array('url' => $result->url, 'alt' => $result->title);
}

print_r($results);
```

Comment: Add detail to your question, and where exactly you are facing issues

Comment: detail? everything is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `imgsz` URL parameter to set the size. You can't specify the exact size in pixels according to the docs, but you can set one of:

- `imgsz=icon` restricts results to small images
- `imgsz=small|medium|large|xlarge` restricts results to medium-sized images
- `imgsz=xxlarge` restricts results to large images
- `imgsz=huge` restricts results to extra-large images

Source: https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide (scroll down to reference).

To implement this, change your `$json` var to:

```
$json = get_url_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=keyword&imgsz=small');
```

Comment: but i want to search by my sizes. is it impossible?

Comment: You can't specify the exact size in pixels according to the docs. If you need them to be 200x200 in size, grab a size `imgsz` that is larger than 200x200 and then resize them on your server using `imagemagick` or `gd` (there are libraries to do that without to much hassle, f.e. https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize).

Comment: i will use in wordpress theme. :(. 
do you know different way for this? thanks everything

Comment: Wordpress has a `WP_Image_Editor` class since 3.5 which can help you with resizing things. See usage @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor . Good luck.